# Are there more languages than functions?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

My gut says "no", but I don't know why.

For any function $f$ over strings on an alphabet, one can define a language in which every word is just the concatenation of a string $s$, a delimiter, and $f(s)$, or the empty string if $f(s)$ is undefined.  So there at least as many languages as functions.  How can we define a function for every language?  (Forgive my ignorance about languages, automata, etc.  I have not studied in that area.  Perhaps my question is poorly constrained.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the signature of the function.  In computability theory we typically deal with functions with the signature $f:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}$.  There is a one-to-one correspondence between functions $f:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}$ and languages $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$: in particular, the function $f$ corresponds to the language $L=\{x : f(x)=1\}$, and the language $L$ corresponds to the function $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in L$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin L$.

Comment: That's the signature I had in mind.  Give me a minute to digest ....